Android studio debug build fails on windows when windows display language is Arabic
I have an android project on windows that when I build I get Failed to create keystore exception for the gradle task :app:validateSigningDebug.
I suspect this cause.
Cause: invalid date string: Unparseable date: "bd`fafbabf`iGMT+00:00"

I don't know Why the date string looks weird.
I tried to change my regional format to English US but the issue persists.
When I changed the display language from Arabic to English US the build was successful.
I want to build the project successfully without changing the language to English because I'm not the only one who uses this computer.

TLDR: Add set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Duser.language=en in your gradlew.bat. Explanation below.
I ran into a similar issue recently. Gradle would fail when Windows language is set to Arabic with errors like:
Could not find org.codehaus.groovy:groovy:┘ú.┘á.┘í┘º.

It looked like it's getting a mangled version number for all packages; Indo-Arabic numerals were my first guess. A lot of software unfortunately assumes Arabic language implies using them instead of Arabic numerals, regardless of your regional settings.
Running gradle from the command-line with --debug confirmed my suspicion:
2024-11-29T08:11:51.922+0200 [DEBUG] [org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner] Build operation 'Download https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/%D9%A3.%D9%A0.%D9%A1%D9%A7/groovy-%D9%A3.%D9%A0.%D9%A1%D9%A7.pom' started

If you decode the above version string with a URL decoder, you get:
2024-11-29T08:11:51.922+0200[DEBUG][org.gradle.internal.operations.DefaultBuildOperationRunner]Buildoperation'Downloadhttps://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/org/codehaus/groovy/groovy/٣.٠.١٧/groovy-٣.٠.١٧.pom'started

Luckily for us, it's easy enough to instruct Java to use a specific locale. Edit your gradlew.bat and modify the line defining default JVM options as follows:
set DEFAULT_JVM_OPTS=-Duser.language=en

This uses the English language for gradle build and will solve the problem.
